# Azure DevOps pipeline task downloads cache from cloud on private agent

Tags: caching, azure-devops, dependencies, task, azure-pipelines

In azure devops we have a pipeline which runs on several private hosted agents on different mac machines. We defined a cache task to prevent re-downloading dependencies:

```
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'Cache gradle distribution'
  inputs:
    key: 'gradleCache'
    path: 'gradle-6.8'
    cacheHitVar: GRADLE_CACHE_HIT

- script: |
    curl -s https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip --output gradle-6.8-bin.zip
    unzip -q gradle-6.8-bin.zip  # a folder named gradle-6-8 will be created
  condition: eq(variables.GRADLE_CACHE_HIT, 'false')
  displayName: 'Download and install gradle'

- script: |
    export PATH=`pwd`/gradle-6.8/bin:$PATH
    gradle -v
  displayName: 'Gradle version'
```

At the second run the cache is active, but the cache-files are downloaded from the web what misses the point of a cache. Is it possible to achive a "local" cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the default behavior that the cached files are downloaded from the azure devops server on the second run of your pipeline when cache task report a "cache hit".

On the first run, a cache will be created from the files in the folder you specified in `path` field(ie. `gradle-6.8`) of the cache task, and uploaded to azure devops server.

On the second run, when cache task reports a "cache hit". The cached files will be downloaded from the azure devops server to path `gradle-6.8` specified in cache task.

Using cache task is not the best solution for your scenarios. Since you are using private hosted agents, you can use below workarounds to totally skip re-downloading gradle tool.

1, You can pre-install gradle-6.8 to the mac machines where your private hosted agents are hosted. So that there is no need to download and install gradle in your pipeline.

2, You can download the gradle-6.8 to a different place other than in the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` on private hosted agents, which could be auto cleaned in the future pipeline run.

For example in windows machines: On the first run of your pipeline. You can save the gradle-6.8 to `D:\custom\folder\forPipelinetool` instead of `C:\Agent\_work\1\s` (ie. `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`).

Then gradle-6.8 will be saved in a different place on the agent machines. And there will be not need to download gradle-6.8 in the following run. You can then disable the script task which downloads the gradle-6.8.

Comment: my gradle@2 task try to download new gradle instead of using cached one , can elaborate more how to use cached gradle in android with example ?